# I'm having issues making the y loop in my percentage guesser work

Tags: python

I was studying a couple of days ago, but for the past few days my studies have been halted by a problem: an infinite while loop. I encountered this problem completing task 3 on assignment 1 of MIT's Introduction to CS with python. The directions for this task are below.

Part C: Finding the right amount to save away
In Part B, you had a chance to explore how both the percentage of your salary that you save each month 
and your annual raise affect how long it takes you to save for a down payment.  This is nice, but
suppose you want to set a particular goal, e.g. to be able to afford the down payment in three years.
How much should you save each month to achieve this?  In this problem, you are going to write a 
program to answer that question.  To simplify things, assume:

1. Your semi­annual raise is .07 (7%)
2. Your investments have an annual return of 0.04 (4%)
3. The down payment is 0.25 (25%) of the cost of the house
4. The cost of the house that you are saving for is $1M.

You are now going to try to find the best rate of savings to achieve a down payment on a $1M house in 36 months. Since hitting this exactly is a challenge, we simply want your savings to be within $100 of 
the required down payment.

In ps1c.py, write a program to calculate the best savings rate, as a function of your starting salary.

You should use bisection search to help you do this efficiently. You should keep track of the number of steps it takes your bisections search to finish. You should be able to reuse some of the code you wrote
for part B in this problem.

Because we are searching for a value that is in principle a float, we are going to limit ourselves to two decimals of accuracy (i.e., we may want to save at 7.04% ­­ or 0.0704 in decimal - but we are not going to worry about the difference between 7.041% and 7.039%).  This means we can search for an
integer between 0 and 10000 (using integer division), and then convert it to a decimal percentage (using float division) to use when we are calculating the current_savings after 36 months. By using this range, there are only a finite number of numbers that we are searching over, as opposed to the
infinite number of decimals between 0 and 1. This range will help prevent infinite loops. The reason we use 0 to 10000 is to account for two additional decimal places in the range 0% to 100%. Your code should print out a decimal (e.g. 0.0704 for 7.04%).

Try different inputs for your starting salary, and see how the percentage you need to save changes to reach your desired down payment.  Also keep in mind it may not be possible for to save a down payment in a year and a half for some salaries. In this case your function should notify the user that it 
is not possible to save for the down payment in 36 months with a print statement. Please make your program print results in the format shown in the test cases below.

*Note: There are multiple right ways to implement bisection search/number of steps so your results may not perfectly match those of the test case.*

Hints

● There may be multiple savings rates that yield a savings amount that is within $100 of the required down payment on a $1M house. In this case, you can just return any of the possible values.

● Depending on your stopping condition and how you compute a trial value for bisection search, your number of steps may vary slightly from the example test cases.

● Watch out for integer division when calculating if a percentage saved is appropriate and when calculating final decimal percentage savings rate.

● Remember to reset the appropriate variable(s) to their initial values for each iteration of bisection search.

**Test Case 1**

```
In[1]: Enter the starting salary: 150000 

Out[1]: Best savings rate: 0.4411   

Steps in bisection search: 12
```

**Test Case 2**

```
In[2]: Enter the starting salary: 300000

Out[2]: Best savings rate: 0.2206 

Steps in bisection search: 9
```

**Test Case 3**

```
In[3]: Enter the starting salary: 10000

Out[3]: It is not possible to pay the down payment in three years.
```

My created code for this task is the fallowing.

```
annual_income = float(input("put your income here:"))
down_payment = float(250000)
high = float(1)
low = float(0)
rate = float((high + low)/2)
steps = 0
m = 0
interest = 0.04
savings = 0
while m <= 36:
  if m % 6 == 0:
    annual_income = annual_income * float(1.07)
  savings = savings + (annual_income * rate)/12 + (annual_income * interest)/12
  m += 1
x = float(savings - down_payment)
while x != 0.01:
  if rate > 1:
    break
  elif x < 0.01:
    low = rate
  elif x > 0.01:
    high = rate
  steps += 1
if x == 0.01:
  print(str(rate))
  print(str(steps))
else:
  print("cant be done")
```

By inserting print statements in this code, I've found that it runs smoothly until it hits the while loop. When I put print statements in the while loop, my browser crashes, which means the while loop is working, but it never stops working. I have spent about 3 days trying to decipher why this happens, but unfortunately, my efforts have lead to no progress. So I've turned here to see if someone could tell me why my while loop continues to run infinitely. I've tried to be as clear as I can in this post, but if for some reason I've failed in this goal feel free to ask questions. Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Please format question in a more laconic and friendly way:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to effectively help you, please pare down your post to a clear and specific question. Reference the SO help here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Anthony.  It's in your best interest to finish your [tour] and see [ask] on how to create a [mcve] on how to create a clear and concise question.  At the moment your question is overwhelming with superfluous information that is unlikely to attract answers.  You could try to simplify it down to your minimal code, your expected input/outcome and actual input/outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have check and it seem stuck at the second while loop.

So let's go step by step. You set `m=0`, as long as `m <= 36` it holds true, stepping in
if and only if `m % 6 == 0` this is true, if so do some code, then increment m by 1.

Now we are at `x = (savings - down_payment)`, x will output some high positive or negative number lets say $20,000.

As long as `x != 0.01` which will always be true because x will never be 0.01. So your while loop will be infinitely stuck here

Comment: Forgot to mention your rate is always constant 0.5. so rate will never be  greater than 1 and will never break.